# how to change full calendar view on day click in react

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using react full calendar and wondering how I can allow users to change the calendar view to timeGridDay when clicking on a day in the monthly view.

Comment: Your question need to include a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example / Sample Code**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on your issue.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

by allowing `navLinks` you can do this. so if the user clicks on a date
they will see a single day view.

```
<FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    events={events}
    //allowing user to click on date.
    navLinks={true}
/>
```

Comment: this is a good answer, thanks for sharing. but one question. after I click `navLinks`, how can I go back to the `initialView`?

Comment: @devdude19289 for that insert a button anywhere on the page. and pass a ref={} on calendar components.  and on button click change view by changeView API from the full calendar 

`<ref variable you passed on calendar components >.current.getApi().changeView('<whatever view you want>')`